# Speed up sqlFetch()

Tags: database, r

I am working with an Oracle database and like to fetch a table with 30 million records.

```
library(RODBC)
ch <- odbcConnect("test", uid="test_user", 
                  pwd="test_pwd", 
                  believeNRows=FALSE, readOnly=TRUE)
db <- sqlFetch(ch, "test_table")
```

For 1 million records the process needs 1074.58 sec. Thus, it takes quite a while for all 30 million records. Is there any possiblity to speed up the process?

I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: RODBC against Oracle is crazy slow. Dump to a local csv at the database end, transfer over network file sharing and then load into R via sqldf::read.csv.sql. See: http://www.cerebralmastication.com/2009/11/loading-big-data-into-r/

Comment: Thanks for the link. Do you have any experience whether the "ROracle" package is better in terms of performance? To me, it really seems counterintuitive to create a dump.

Comment: @majom At work, I have to write queries against an Oracle Data warehouse and pulling the data into R is painfully slow.  I have never been able to get ROracle up and running.  Instead of sqlFetch, I try to write targeted queries to get at the data I need.  This minimizes the data transfer (a bit) and leverages the Oracle in-database speed.  I don't work with data as large as yours, so my process fits my needs (for now).  Not ideal, but works.

Comment: Thanks, Btibert3. I just came across the following performance comparison between ROracle and RJDBC http://guyharrison.squarespace.com/blog/2011/5/20/rjdbc-20-performance-improvements.html. Probably, I have really to try ROracle, even though I am not sure if RODBC and RJDBC are 100% comparable in terms of performance.

Answer (score 0):

You could try making a system call through the R terminal
to a mySQL shell using the system() command. Process your data externally and only load what you need as output.