# Comparing database connectivity performance in r

Tags: oracle, r, rodbc, rjdbc

Our organization uses oracle databases extensively - we have hundreds of thousands of records that we pull into r and then perform statistics.  We've been using the RODBC package almost exclusively, but I've just got rOracle to work, and now I'm wondering which package is "better".

Is anyone aware of any benchmarking/testing/comparisons between the various ways one can connect to oracle in R?  I've been searching, and have found http://guyharrison.squarespace.com/blog/2011/5/20/rjdbc-20-performance-improvements.html, which indicates that ROracle is pretty similar to RJDBC, but I haven't found anything relating roracle to rodbc.  A similar question is asked in the comments here - [Speed up sqlFetch()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13289796/speed-up-sqlfetch) - but there's no real answer there.

I'm going to do some testing myself, but I'm not sure I'd be confident in my own benchmarking abilities.  I'll post back here if I find anything significant.

Comment: Now you're just 1459 rep short!

Comment: Oracle did some benchmarking for their blog: https://blogs.oracle.com/R/entry/r_to_oracle_database_connectivity